# Check for a GET variable in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

so I'm making a simple log in form in my site using Jade and ExpressJS. It's all working, the only problem I'm having is when the user enters incorrect log in details. When they enter wrong details I redirect them to the log in page with a parameter in the URL (`/admin?falseLogIn`). My question is: how can I check if this GET variable exists in my jade view?

This is my code:

**log-in.jade**

```
form(action="/log-in" method="post")
    label Username
    input(type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username")
    label Password
    input(type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password")
    input(type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin-top: 15px;" value="Log In")
```

**app.js**

```
app.get("/admin",function(req, res){

    if(req.session.userName){
        res.render("admin", {session_name: req.session.userName});
    }else{
        res.render("log-in");
    }

});

app.post("/log-in", function(req, res){

    var admin = Admin.findOne({"username": req.body.username, "password": req.body.password});
    admin.count(function(error, count){
        //console.log(count);
        if(count > 0){
            req.session.userName = req.body.username;
            res.redirect("/admin");
        }else{
            res.redirect("/admin?falseLogIn");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried the following inside my jade view but get an error `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`:

```
- var page = window.location.pathname

if page === "/admin?falseLogIn"
    .alert.alert-danger Error! Wrong details, please try again!
```

I come from a PHP background, so in PHP i would be able to check directly in the html using:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['falseLogIn'])){// display error to user } ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Req.query.falseLogin in the admin page controller

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, but where exactly do I need to put that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would recommend using full key-values for your query string, `/admin?login=false`

Then you use `req.query` to get the specific variable and pass into your jade view or using `res.locals` to make the variable accessible in your views.

**app.js**

```
app.get("/admin",function(req, res){

  res.locals.login = req.query.login; // this would be accessible in your view as 'login'

  if (req.session.userName) {
    res.render("admin", {session_name: req.session.userName});
  } else {
    res.render("log-in", {
      login: req.query.login, // or pass variable to your view directly, also accessible in your view as 'login'
    });
  }
});
```

Reasoning. I don't think it's good practice to parse your url query directly in your view. While that is fine for raw php like your example using $_GET, if you use a MVC framework, like Laravel for example, you quickly move away from that. Let the controller do its job of handling logic based on queries and handing off the relevant information to views. Then in your view, its should be simple presentation logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'm kinda new to this so I'm still trying to get the hang of things. So yeah, it's working now. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write you script under `script(type='text/javascript').`

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var page = window.location.pathname
```

But if you want to compare the url, you should get the `search` part instead of `pathname`:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var page = window.location.search
  if(page === '?falseLogIn'){/* some code here, display the error */}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the script tag and I'm able to get the path and the search query (/admin?falseLogIn). The only problem now is when I try to compare the URL to display the error message. That part isn't working.

Comment: Actually,  `window.location.pathname` doesn't include the search part of the url, I have just update the answer, please check it.